Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol - fixing Unassigned Conversion Events
I'm trying to send server-side conversion events to Google Analytics 4 using the Measurement Protocol. The events I'm sending are trial start and subscription paid events. However, when I check the Traffic Report page in GA, all of our conversion events are showing up as 'Unassigned'.
I've been sending the events with client_id and user_id parameters, but I've read that including the session_id parameter is necessary to fix this issue. The GA documentation isn't very clear about the details of session_id specifically in terms of Measurement Protocol, so I have a few questions:

The session_id is a timestamp, so should it be the most recent session_id or the original session_id from when the user first visited the page?
I've also seen some posts mentioning the need to include the engagement_time_msec parameter. Is this accurate, and if so, what should this parameter contain given that I'm sending trial or payment notifications?

